# compiler error when put them together

Tags: haskell, binary-search

I write program for searching in index list of tuple by **binary search** I write and work fine

```
superBubble::(Ord t) =>[[t]]->[[t]]
superBubble a=map bubbleSort a
combining::[BookInfo]->[Int]
combining books= bubbleSort(map index books)  
 binsearch :: [Int] -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -- list, value, low, high, return int
 binsearch xs value low high
  | high < low       = -1
  | xs!!mid > value  = binsearch xs value low (mid-1)
  | xs!!mid < value  = binsearch xs value (mid+1) high
  | otherwise        = mid
   where
   mid = low + ((high - low) `div` 2)
  final::[BookInfo]->Int->Int->Int->Int 
  final vs key s r= binsearch concat( combining vs) key s r
```

and the other functions work propaply but when i add it to the hole give me an error

the error is unexcpted  '|' the first one  but why?

Comment: The second arrow in `final::[BookInfo]->Int-<Int->Int->Int` has its head the wrong way.

Comment: You don't think it would be a good idea to take a look at a Haskell tutorial/book of some sorts, to learn the basics, and then go back to writing more complicated code? While people don't mind helping, you seem to come here every time you need help with the smallest issue. It's best to be able to help yourself.

Comment: I *really* think you should use more than one space for your indents. I suggest four spaces minimum. It will make this kind of error obvious. A good text editor will keep track of your indents for you.

Comment: Chris Taylor can you give me a good compiler name ? I am using GHC

Comment: GHC is pretty much _the_ compiler for Haskell nowadays. Stick with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lines from `binsearch ::` are indented one more space than the lines before it. Unindent each of those lines by one space.

Additionally, the lines from `final::` onwards are indented two more spaces than the initial lines. Unindent each of these lines by two spaces.

Finally, as Daniel points out, you have a `-<` in your `final::` line, instead of a `->`. *(Which you have now corrected in your posted code, thus confusing anyone who looks at this question in future.)*

---

Correct code:

```
superBubble::(Ord t) =>[[t]]->[[t]]
superBubble a=map bubbleSort a
combining::[BookInfo]->[Int]
combining books= bubbleSort(map index books)  
binsearch :: [Int] -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -- list, value, low, high, return int
binsearch xs value low high
 | high < low       = -1
 | xs!!mid > value  = binsearch xs value low (mid-1)
 | xs!!mid < value  = binsearch xs value (mid+1) high
 | otherwise        = mid
  where
  mid = low + ((high - low) `div` 2)
final::[BookInfo]->Int->Int->Int->Int 
final vs key s r= binsearch concat( combining vs) key s r
```

(And you need to include definitions of `bubbleSort`, `BookInfo` and `index` as well.)

---

Why is your indentation an error?

Because it makes `binsearch` look as if it is part of the value of `combining`, instead of a separate function. The first `|` is the first character that can't possibly be part of an expression.

Comment: mmm.. for that I thank u for explaining and for my bad editing can u give my the link of FAQ of editing

Comment: thank u it work properly and forgive my bad editing I didn't know that before

Comment: I slove all my problem can I put it as answer?